# C# unit testing using mocks without interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, interface, moq

In order to properly unit test some of my classes I need to mock the class objects being used by the main class being tested. This is a simple process if all the objects being used implements the interface **and** I only need to use the methods form that interface. However, and here is the problem:

Interfaces are a contract on what other developers should expect in that class. Therefore all interface methods, properties etc. are public. Any good code should also have good encapsulation. Therefore I don't want to make all methods in my class public and hence don't declare it in the interface. And as a result I can not mock and setup these internal method that is used in my main class.

Other options I looked into was using an abstract class that can have different access modifiers and I can have the correct methods in it be internal or private etc. But since I want the class being mocked to be available is a public property of interface type for other developers to use, I need it be an interface, but now its not compatible anymore since my main class cant call the internal method anymore as its defined as an interface. Catch 22. (In case you were wondering, using virtual for methods will have the same problem as using an abstract class).

I have searched for similar questions regarding C# mocking and did not find the same problem I have. And please don't be philosophical on "C# isn't good language for testing" or such stuff. That's not an answer.

Any ideas?

I added this code example to make it easier to see the problem described above.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyService.Tests")]

public interface IMyService
{
    MethodABC()
    ...
}

public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public void MethodABC()
    {
        ...
    }
    
    internal void Initialize()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public sealed partial class MyMain
{
    public IMyService Service { get; private set; }
    private MyService _service;
    
    ...
    
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        // This method is in interface and can be used outside the project when this assembly is referenced
        _service.MethodABC() 
        ...
        
        // This method is and internal method inside the class not to be seen or used outside the project. 
        // 1) When running this method through unit test that mocked the IMyService will fail here since initialize don't exist which is correct.
        // 2) Mocking the MyService will require "virtual" to be added to all methods used and don't provide a interface/template for a developers if 
        //    they want to swap the service out.
        // 3) Changing the interface to abstract class and mocking that allows for making this an internal method and also set it up in mock to do 
        //    something for unit test and provides contract other developers can implement and pass in to use a different service, but requires 
        //    "override" for all methods to be used from "outside" this assembly. This is best solution but require changes to code for sole purpose
        //    of testing which is an anti-pattern.
        _service.Initialize() 
        ...
    }
}

// Unit test method in test project

[TestClass]
public class MyMainTests
{

    private Mock<IMyService> _myServiceMock = new Mock<IMyService>();

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyMain_Test_SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        SomeMethod()
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help to provide a [mre] of code that shows your problem (e.g. the class structure you currently have along with the code you're looking to unit test)

Comment: This is not a question that require an code example. If you don't know how an interface or abstract class get mocked then you wont have a solution to the problem. Maybe you don't like reading, so Ill sum it up. I need to mock a internal method while exposing the object as an interface without adding code just for testing purposes.

Comment: The way you’ve summed it up is different from what I read in your original question, but mocking internal methods seems to defeats the purpose of mocking frameworks.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem you're describing, but when I've wanted to signal that an interface is meant primarily as a development detail, or as an injection point, I've declared it as "internal interface {}". Then only that assembly can access it (unless you're also using the InternalsVisibleTo attribute). The "contract" is still there but it isn't usable in dependent projects.

Comment: I attempted to add code example to make problem clearer. Code is easier to understand than English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there don't seem to be a clean way of doing this. In order to create a mock  using Moq, it needs to be either an interface, abstract class or virtual methods.

- Interfaces cant have encapsulation lower than public. Using a internal interface will still force you to create "Public" methods.
- Virtual methods allow access modifiers but do not provide an injectable object with a contract to be used by Moq other developers using the main class.
- The ideal solution  would not require code changes just for the purpose of making it unit testable. This unfortunately don't seem to be possible.

Which brings me to an abstract class that can provide a template (semi interface) that can be handled like an interface but will require "override" for all contract methods but at least will allow correct access modifiers for methods.

This still goes against clean code as I will need to add code to all my methods for the sole purpose of making it unit testable.

This is something Microsoft can look into for new .Net C# features. I will check if they have a feature request for this already.

Answer (score 0):

Interface testing doesn't make sense. Interface doesn't say anything about "what it should do". When I need test something with interface, I make MockClass in my NUnit testing class. This class works only for few tests, and it is internal. If you have same namespaces for your tested class and your tests, there should be internal enough. So it is not public. But still you cannot test any private methods.

Sometimes it is annoying, but I cannot have nice code in my tests. But it is not strange.

Comment: It is possible to test private methods with "PrivateObject Class". However the need for this usually indicate wrong testing. Only Public methods should be tested, but to do that sometimes require mocking internal methods used inside the public method.

Answer (score 0):

I get the point of testing only public methods and properties but sometimes this limitation just makes no sense as well as using interfaces just to support unit tests.

My workaround is to inherit the class I am testing, add public access methods and then call protected base class members from it.

Comment: You are correct in that only public methods should be tested. However these public method can call internal methods from a object created by a factory. In these cases this factory class usually gets mocked and injected to provide mock "helper" classes. These helper classes can have internal methods that gets called and will fail if not available in mock.

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider is to specify the internal actions on an `internal interface` that you can then use to mock those actions. Given your example, you could add:

```
internal interface IInitialize
{
    void Initialize();
}
```

And then implement this in your class alongside your public interface:

```
public class MyService : IMyService, IInitialize
```

And then your consuming class can use the interface as needed:

```
public sealed partial class MyMain
{
    public MyMain(IMyService myService)
    {
        Service = myService;
    }

    public IMyService Service { get; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        (Service as IInitialize)?.Initialize();
        Service.MethodABC();
    }
}
```

Now in the unit test you can utilize the `As<TInterface>()` method in Moq to handle the multiple interfaces (read [the docs](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#advanced-features)):

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    Mock<IMyService> myServiceMock = new Mock<IMyService>();
    Mock<IInitialize> myServiceInitializeMock = myServiceMock.As<IInitialize>();
    //myServiceMock.Setup(s => s.MethodABC()).Whatever
    //myServiceInitializeMock.Setup(s => s.Initialize()).Whatever

    MyMain myMain = new MyMain(myServiceMock.Object);
    myMain.SomeMethod();

    myServiceMock.Verify(s => s.MethodABC(), Times.Once);
    myServiceInitializeMock.Verify(s => s.Initialize(), Times.Once);
}
```

Note the following remark on `As<TInterface>()`:

> This method can only be called before the first use of the mock
> Moq.Mock`1.Object property, at which point the runtime type has
> already been generated and no more interfaces can be added to it.

Also note that the use of `As<TInterface>()` also requires the following attribute to allow the mock proxy access to implement the internal interface:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try and find a solution :). I drafted a long reply explaining why this still don’t solve the problem but I am limited by characters in the comment so will give the main problem. I basically already tried a similar approach but any interface (even if it’s "internal"), require all the methods that implements it to be "public". Forcing me to make methods "public" in my main class when they should not be.